# Passing modified list to each node of binary tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tree

I am writing a function to grow a tree:

```
def collect_append(collect,split):
 collect.append(split)
 return collect         


def tree(string,passwords,collect): #collect is a list and passwords is also a list

 matching_list = []
 match = 0
 if len(string)==0:
  print(collect)
  return 0
 for j in passwords:
   for i in range(min(len(j),len(string))):
     if string[i]!=j[i]:
      break
 else :
   matching_list.append(j)
   match = match + 1
 if match == 0:
  return 1
 else:
  for split in matching_list:
   x =tree(string.strip(split),passwords,collect_append(collect,split))
 return x
```

My question is, for each split in matching_list(say two), I want to add different strings to the existing list at that point (i.e. I want two versions of list).

In this case the `collect_append` function I use is modifying the list in first iteration of the `for` loop and using the same for further iterations. What I want is to just modify the `collect` list just for the parameter and without permanently changing it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two serious errors in your code.  First, this `else` clause is never executed:

```
for j in passwords:
    for i in range(...):
        if ...:
            break
else:
    ...
```

Since the `break` is in the inner `for` loop, the outer `for` loop is never exited via a `break` so the `else` is never taken. Second, this doesn't do what you want:

```
string.strip(split)
```

You're trying to remove `split` from the beginning of `string` but you're removing all the letters in `split` from both ends of `string`, bruising it badly.  Here's one way to do it correctly:

```
string[len(split):]
```

I'm going to go out on a limb, and rewrite your code to do what I think you want it to do:

```
def tree(string, passwords, collect):

    length = len(string)

    if length == 0:
        return False

    matching_list = []

    for j in passwords:
        i = min(len(j), length)

        if string[:i] == j[:i]:
            matching_list.append(j)

    if not matching_list:
        return False

    result = False

    for split in matching_list:
        local_collection = list([split])
        if split == string or tree(string[len(split):], passwords, local_collection):
            collect.append(local_collection)
            result = True

    return result

collection = []

print(tree('dogcatcher', ['cat', 'catch', 'cher', 'dog', 'dogcat', 'dogcatcher', 'er'], collection))

print(collection)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
True
[['dog', ['cat', ['cher']], ['catch', ['er']]], ['dogcat', ['cher']], ['dogcatcher']]
%
```

Giving you a tree of all the ways to assemble `string` from the words in `passwords`.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted